# Specific user-based admin view

Tags: views, users

For testing whether Drupal 7 runs on an local nginx server:

One of the user should get more rights than an editor/writer, but less than an admin. Is there a way to create a 2nd specific admin role without certain permissions (e.g. Admin VBO Views)?

Regards, bolshii

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think you just need to create a new role and specify what the user can do and what he cant? I have for example a role which can add new content and nothing more. So they see the admin bar in the top and it only lists add content :) and which types of content they can add.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://example.com/admin/people/permissions to see and change the permissions for administrative, authenticated and anonymous users.

On the upper right hand side of the screen, click 'roles'. 
On the next screen, you can add a role. Use the handles on the left to position the new role above administrator, since it will have only slightly less permissions.

Now, go back to the permissions page to adjust the permissions.

If the default permissions are not granular enough, install contributed modules like nodeaccess.